# azure devops : winrm sql server db deployment task : Connecting to remote server failed

Tags: sql, database, deployment, azure-devops, winrm

Getting below error on winrm SQL server DB deployment task in azure devops ,

Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException: Deployment on one or more machines failed. 
System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException: Connecting to remote server 1xx.xx.xx.xxx failed with the following error message : The

client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting requests. Consult

the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service,

run the following command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig". For more information, see the

about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

Comment: Are you using a private agent or the hosted agent?

Comment: Hi Daniel, using hosted agent2017

Answer (score 0):

The hosted agent doesn't have a route to your on-premise network. You'll need to install and configure a self-hosted agent that resides within the network you're trying to connect to.

Comment: Hi Daniel , please share the deatils how to configure self-hosted agent?

Comment: @Saran There is plenty of documentation readily available from Microsoft. I suggest you start there.